# Error occurs when I connect with socket in Python

Tags: python, sockets

Nice to meet you.
A socket makes a program in Python by Linux (the transmission of a message) ⇒ Windows (the reception), b
ut the following errors occur and cannot connect now.
Linux, Windows are network connection together, and there is the authority to cut.

socket.error: (111, 'Connection refused')

Could you help me!?

Answer (score 2):

111 means the listener is down/not accepting connections - restart the Windows app that should be listening for connections, or disconnect any already-bound clients.

Comment: Also you should make sure there's no firewall blocking inbound connections to that specific port on the windows box